# Phonegap and ajax request

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova

I am working with Android 2.2.  I currently have the application wrapped in **phonegap** with **Sencha**.  I have forms that use an Ajax request to post the information and send it to an email.  It all works fine before I wrap it in **Phonegap**.  I have read that you cannot do Ajax requests through **phonegap** though.  Is there any way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do AJAX requests through a Phonegap app.  I have an app running on both Android and iPhone and it works fine for both local (in app) and remote (mobile to server) communications.  I use jQuery, but I don't suspect that what library I use matters.